# Scaling SockJS keeping track of clients

Tags: node.js

Im in the process of scaling up my Nodejs server which runs a SockJS server. Its a basic chat where the SockJS server stores each connected client.

Basically i store it like this:

```
var clients = [];
var sockets = {};
    // Identify this client
    socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort

    // Put this new client in the list
    clients.push(socket);
    sockets[socket.name] = socket;
```

This is how i write to the socket:

```
sockets[socketName].write("{\"type\":\"type\", \"msg\": \"" + escp(obj.msg) + "\", \"name\": \"" + obj.name+ "\", \"location\": \"" + obj.location + "\"}");
```

My idea is to now scale up and start more instances on Amazon. And i'll have `HAProxy` in the front balacing the load.

The problem is that both people chatting would have to be on the same instance, since the connectedClients isent shared amongst my `ec2 instances`.

Any ideas how to accomplish this? Do i need to store `connectedClients` in a db? (Is that even possible)?

Basically i need to share `sockets` and `clients` between my instances

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably have to store the session connection in redis/mongodb and have those nodes server do pub/sub to the redis in order to have consistent request /response across the node. therefore, when user send message to HAProxy irrespective of which server the HAProxy route the request to the node has check-in redis if there is existing connection.